# Will fighting alongside a Pokemon add it to your Pokedex?

Tags: pokemon-go

Last weeks the Legendary Birds and Lugia were released. After an intense raid battle you could catch these beasts and add them to your Pokedex. However, you were not allowed to leave them in gyms, because they do not want to leave your side (but you can send them back to the Professor, strange enough).

So, if you do not had the opportunity to fight and catch one of these Pokemon, you have (right now, Niantic did not release more information) no chance to encounter them and add them to your Pokedex. The only way to see one of those is fighting alongside them in a gym or raid battle.

If you fight alongside one of these animals with an empty index, will it add it to your Pokedex (as seen, not as caught)?

Comment: Interesting question. I know just battling the raid boss won't register it into the Pokemon, but never considered those battling with you

Comment: Also, after posting this question, [Niantic](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/exclusiveraids) add more info about extending the legendary birds until August 31st

Comment: @Wondercricket yes, indeed. However, the question is of course more general, but most applicable to these birds. For example, I never seen the evolution of Mareep (I even don't know it's name), will it be added if someone fights with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Ran this experiment with a friend tonight. Not with the legendaries, but we did a regular gym battle where I used a Porygon 2. My friend was able to visibly see it on their device during battle but they didn't get Pokedex entry at all.